# Excel: avoid calculation when input cells are empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm designing a world cup score predictor competition for charity.

I currently have this formula to calculate points from a prediction against the real life result:

```
=IF(AND(J5='Tournament SheetoLD'!J5,'Player Sheet'!L5='Tournament SheetoLD'!L5),5,IF(OR(J5-L5='Tournament SheetoLD'!J5-'Tournament SheetoLD'!L5,AND('Player Sheet'!J5>'Player Sheet'!L5,'Tournament SheetoLD'!J5>'Tournament SheetoLD'!L5),AND('Player Sheet'!J5>'Player Sheet'!L5,'Tournament SheetoLD'!J5>'Tournament SheetoLD'!L5)),2,0))
```

Only problem is that when the input cells are blank, it thinks they have equal values and assigns the maximum points to the player.

Is there any way to only calculate the points when the cells are filled (not blank)?

[example of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ALl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to test the values of the J5 and L5 cells.

The first `IF` clause I've added below will write "" to your cell in case J5 or L5 are empty using the [ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) funtion.

**PS**: I replaced the sheet name 'Player Sheet' to 'PS' due to readability purposes.

```
=IF(
    OR(ISBLANK('PS'!J5), ISBLANK('PS'!L5)),
    0,
    IF(
        AND(J5='Tournament SheetoLD'!J5,'PS'!L5='Tournament SheetoLD'!L5),
        5,
        IF(
            OR(
                J5-L5='Tournament SheetoLD'!J5-'Tournament SheetoLD'!L5,
                AND('PS'!J5 > 'PS'!L5, 'Tournament SheetoLD'!J5 > 'Tournament SheetoLD'!L5),
                AND('PS'!J5 > 'PS'!L5, 'Tournament SheetoLD'!J5 > 'Tournament SheetoLD'!L5)),
            2,
            0
        )
    )
)
```

Good luck! ;-)

By the way: It looks like you have duplicated a condition by mistake, or it is just a 'bug':

```
AND('PS'!J5 > 'PS'!L5, 'Tournament SheetoLD'!J5 > 'Tournament SheetoLD'!L5)
```

Comment: Then try using  0  instead of  ""  in the formula above.

Comment: I changed the beginning to =IF(OR(J5="",L5=""),"", and it seems to be working fine. Thanks for the help :)